# Should Java streams be closed Before the backing socket is closed?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, optimization, io

I have the following code:

```
public void disconnect()
{
    running = false;
    if(thread != null)
        thread.interrupt();
    thread = null;

    try
    {
        socket.close();
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

I have a BufferedReader that collects the input from the stream and a PrintWriter that sends messages through the output stream. Should the BufferedReader and the PrintWriter be closed before i close the socket? Is it bad to leave the i/o streams open?

Comment: The code that uses the stream should be able to react to the IO exceptions which can (and will) result from having the backing closed unexpectedly (either by local code or by network error, etc).

Comment: @user166390 Network errors don't result in 'having the backing [socket] closed'. It stays open until the application that created it closes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Java Networking Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html)

> "You should close any streams connected to a socket before you close the socket itself."

Comment: That's not adequate. See my answer.

Comment: EJP is right, a full answer to the question needs to cover the bit that asks whether it is BAD to leave the higher level streams open.  And the quoted sentence doesn't cover that.

Answer (score 4):

You *must* close the *output* stream, so it gets flushed. That closes both the socket and the input stream. Closing any one of those closes the other two. You don't need to close the input stream at all. Strictly speaking for safety's sake you should probably also close the socket itself in a finally block.

Comment: Not closing the input stream leads to leaked system resources, so I really don't like that advice.. yes when the stream is GCed sometime I think its finalizer does release the resources, but using the GC for resource handling is frowned upon for good reasons too.

Comment: @Voo You are mistaken. Not closing the input stream does *not* 'lead to leaked system resources'. The only 'system resource' in play here is the socket, and it does get closed.

Comment: @user207421 Having seen your argument about closing socket related resource in many posts, I still really want to know: Since closing output closes socket too, why do we also need to close socket for "safety's sake"? in what specific scenario would this "for safety" precaution show his power?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't close the `BufferedWriter`, you might lose some buffered but un-flushed data.

There's also a school of thought that says you shouldn't use `PrintWriter`, or to be careful if you do, because it swallows `IOException`s.

Answer (score 0):

Every stream you open uses OS resources. When you call close on a stream it is marked for Garbage Collection and the memory is freed after GC. If you don't close the stream, it will be closed by GC (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#close%28%29) but it's not clear at all, when GC will hit that object.

So it's always better to close a stream to instantly free memory.

Comment: Closing a stream releases the underlying resource, e.g. a socket or file `fd`. Closing a stream does *not* mark it for garbage collection, or make it available for GC in any way. Indeed nothing marks it for garbage collection. Java GC works by reachability, not by marking.