# Will the streams associated with sockets closed automatically when the socket is closed?

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I am using Java sockets (TCP) to communicate with the server.
My question is, Will the input and output streams associated with a socket is automatically closed, when the socket is closed? is it safe to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) -

```
You should close any streams connected to a socket before you close the
socket itself.
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11043520/207421) "You *must* close the output stream, so it gets flushed. That closes both the socket and the input stream. Closing any one of those closes the other two. You don't need to close the input stream at all. Strictly speaking for safety's sake you should probably also close the socket itself in a finally block."

You can explicit stop the incoming data from the inputStream as follows

```
yourSocket.shutdownInput();
```

This places input stream for the socket at "end of stream". Any data sent to the input stream side of the socket is acknowledged and then silently discarded.You can still send data to the output socket. Again you have to close the output stream and the socket.

Similarly see [shutdownOutput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownOutput%28%29).

Comment: @EJP ACK. Just wanted to answer quickly. My sincere apologies.

Comment: (1) You are supposed to acknowledge your sources. You've edited your question and you still haven't provided a proper attribution. (2) Shutting down the socket for input doesn't close the input stream. It remains open for reading. Downvote remains. Flagged as plagiarism.

Comment: "Any data sent to the input side of the socket is acknowledged and then silently discarded." No. This is platform-dependent. BSD behaves that way. Linux doesn't discard the data, so a sender will eventually block. Windows incorrectly sends a reset. Downvote remains.

Comment: @EJP That is what the java docs say http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownInput()

Comment: The Javadoc is incorrect. I researched this extensively for my book on Java Networking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you close either the `Socket,` its input stream, or its output stream, the other two are closed automatically.

Having said that, you should as a matter of good practice always close the outermost output stream or writer you have wrapped around the socket, and maybe close the socket itself in a finally block. That way you ensure that the final output gets flushed. If you are using buffered output streams or writers and you don't do that, you will lose data in the buffer.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will close sockets like that.